# A* pathfinding on Hexmap in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, path-finding, a-star

I want to use the `A*` path finding algorithm in my game with a hexagonal map. I found some JavaScript implementations [here](http://www.matthewtrost.org/projects/astar/) and [here](http://devpro.it/examples/astar/index2.html). But is there any possibility to apply it to the hexagonal map?

In most cases it uses some external file. I think I must edit it. But I´m not so good in JavaScript to edit it.

Do you know some implementation that can be used to the hexagonal map?

Comment: check this out, its quite elaborate. [http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44812/finding-shortest-path-on-a-hexagonal-grid][1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://vanreijmersdal.nl/development/experiments/javascript/hexpath/

http://www.matthewtrost.org/projects/astar/ (link is dead -- found a gist at https://gist.github.com/1168189)

Comment: Moved the code from my website to github: https://github.com/nreijmersdal/hexpath